# How to map seperated properties of a class using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some mapping classes that has a bunch of different properties.

```cs
class A 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
    // Format is: Postal Code, Street, City, Country
    public string Address { get; set; } 
}
```

and I want to split the address into seperated properties in class B.

- A.X map to B.Lat, A.Y map to B.Lon
- A.Address string split with commas and set B class.

```cs
class B 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lon { get; set; } // map to X
    public string Lat { get; set; } // map to Y
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

So is there any way to do this using reflection or any 3rd party libraries?

You can think this dto cobject transfer.

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Please include your recent coding attempt(s) in your question and explain why it doesn't work or which error(s) it produces.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question but... why not the property setter for do the parsing you require?

Comment: Please define the relationship between A and B. Is B a subclass of A ?

Comment: @DrkDeveloper . . . As far as I understand, it is desired that an instance of class `A` should somehow be transformed (or mapped) to an instance of class `B`, correctly filling all properties in object `B` from the data in object `A`.

Comment: why not `new B(A toCopy)` ctor? I don't understant. There's something we don't know. Or I'm stupid (highly possible)

Comment: @DrkDeveloper . . . I think something like that (either a constructor or a "stand-alone" mapping function) is indeed desired by the OP. But they didn't provide an example what they tried so far... so it is indeed a bit unclear.

Comment: You can think this DTO transfer objects.

Comment: @barteloma it doesn't matter whether this is a DTO or not. Creating one object from another can be a single line of code, except for `Address` which needs to be parsed. Again, this can be a simple `Split`. Have you tried *anything*?  What prevents you from writing these lines?

Comment: @barteloma any library you use will need *more* code, and you'll still have to write the custom parsing logic. Have you tried `return new B{Name=a.Name, Lat=a.X,...}` ?

Comment: should this mapping be bidirectional? are there any other constraints? you could just use a constructor (following the direction of the dependency between the two classes); one of the most famous libraries that can do this is automapper

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
public class A_DTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
    // Format is: Postal Code, Street, City, Country
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public A_DTO(B_DTO b)
    {
        Name = b.Name;
        X = b.Lon;
        Y = b.Lat;
        var str = new StringBuilder(b.PostalCode);
        str.Append($", " + b.Street);
        str.Append($", " + b.City);
        str.Append($", " + b.Country);
        Address = str.ToString();
    }
}

public class B_DTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lon { get; set; } // map to X
    public string Lat { get; set; } // map to Y
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public B_DTO(A_DTO a)
    {
        Name = a.Name;
        Lon = a.X;
        Lat = a.Y;

        var splits = a.Address.Split(',');
        if(splits.Length!= 4)
            throw ...;

        PostalCode = splits[0];
        Street = splits[1];
        City = splits[2];
        Country = splits[3];
    }
```

*: This could be improved with Span avoiding a great number of allocations if you have a lot objets.

Answer (score 0):

If your address is always in the "Postal Code, Street, City, Country" format, then it should be easy, you can add this constructor (or a static function or whatnot) to your `B` class:

```cs
public B(A input)
{
    Name = input.Name;
    Lon = input.X;
    Lat = input.Y;

    var addressParts = input.Address.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);

    if (addressParts.Length != 4)
    {
        throw new FormatException($"Address string is not in <Postal Code, Street, City, Country> format - {input.Address}");
    }

    PostalCode = addressParts[0];
    Street = addressParts[1];
    City = addressParts[2];
    Country = addressParts[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this mapping through **reflection only if you have same name and type** of the properties in both classes else you will land into putting too many conditions.

### Using Reflection Code

```
public class PropertyCopier<TParent, TChild> where TParent : class
                                            where TChild : class
{
    public static void Copy(TParent parent, TChild child)
    {
        var parentProperties = parent.GetType().GetProperties();
        var childProperties = child.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var parentProperty in parentProperties)
        {
            foreach (var childProperty in childProperties)
            {
                if (parentProperty.Name == childProperty.Name && parentProperty.PropertyType == childProperty.PropertyType)
                {
                    childProperty.SetValue(child, parentProperty.GetValue(parent));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Other ways

If name or types are not same in that case you need to write converters for the same. Similar to what other folks have mentioned.